# SQL Server migrate from local to AWS?

Tags: sql-server, migration

I did the development and now look forward to migrating it to AWS. First, I need to get this database there. So it is a database in SQL Server, I also have SQL Server running on AWS. How do I migrate the database over? Thanks.

EDIT: Hi, all the tutorials i found from Google are too much detailed or difficult to follow (those ones without images). Is there a similar thing like exporting a .sql file then import it?

Answer (score 1):

The AWS documentation covers most (all) of what you need

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html